# Use IF function to check if parameter is set without having to also create a condition

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I want to do this: https://cloudonaut.io/optional-parameter-in-cloudformation/

Basically just want to use IF to check if a parameter was set at deploy time

But I *really* resent having to create this weird middle-man "condition" for this. It's very convoluted, not readable, and I'll need to do it for every param I add that I want this behaviour for, so it's not scalable either.

Is there any way to just set the default value of a param to `False` and use IF to see if it was set without creating this weird "condition" thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is **not support**. From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-conditions.html#intrinsic-function-reference-conditions-if) `Fn::If` requires the first argument to be condition:

> A reference to a **condition in the Conditions section**. Use the condition's name to reference it.